# Excel IF arguemtn with 4+ conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm looking to create a formula with 3+ conditions. I've tried some of the suggestions on this forum but cannot seem to get my formula quite right -- I'm getting a "FALSE" argument usually, so the problem is in the way(s) I'm nesting the arguments, I believe.  Here is the situation:  There is a number in D13.  If D13 is between >=2 and <=4, then "Text 1". If D13 is <2 or >4 and <=7, then "Text 2". If D13 is >7, then "Text 3".  Thanks.

Comment: How can D13 be both <2 AND between 4 and 7? That may be your problem...

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Comment: Should have said.... If D13<2 OR between 4 and 7, then "Text 2".

Comment: You have `IF D13 is between 2 and 4 then "Text 1"`, and then `IF D13 is less than 2, or between 4 and 7 then "Text2"`.  If the number is 4, Text 1 will always get picked... do you mean to include 4 in multiple conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're after something like this?

```
=IF(D13<2, "Text 2", IF(D13<5, "Text 1", IF(D13<8, "Text 2", "Text 3")))
```

But your ranges are mucked up, so I had to guess .. adjust above as necessary.

Comment: Stack Overflow really isn't for guesses; it's usually better to wait and see what the actual requirements are, than potentially send the user down the wrong path because the requirements aren't understood

Comment: Understood, however, it's not the larger issue that's not understood, it's the minor range boundaries .. which are easy to adjust, as I indicated.

Answer (score 0):

- `Text1` if >=2 AND < 4
- `Text2` if ((>=4 AND <= 7) OR < 2),
- `Text3` if >
  7, then:

  ```
  =IF(AND(D13>=2,D13<4),"Text1",IF(OR(D13<2,AND(D13>=4,D13<=7)),"Text2","Text3"))
  ```

Comment: THANKS you Steve16351. This worked perfectly.  I had my parentheses in the wrong place(s).